# 3 channels - Joint color histogram

Tags: python, computer-vision, histogram

I have a question about joint color histograms. They seem to be frequently used be (for example [here](https://www.cis.uab.edu/kddm/seminar_home/Lin_Sept25_tree-camera-ready.pdf) page 5) but I cannot find a proper definition in a research paper and I am wondering how they work.

Is they're somewhere a description of the algorithm or even a python librairy handling such histograms?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joint histograms are just histograms in higher dimensional space. [Color histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_histogram) and joint color histogram are synonymous when referring to (binned) distribution of colors, with "joint" only emphasizing the polychromatic or multidimensional nature of the color bins, as opposed to one dimensional histograms whose sole spatial dimension being intensity.

Comment: Oh Ok, make sense. Thanks for this explaination!